# map function value not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In `console.log` the api fetched data are displaying but in browser itis
showing only white screen. In map function have to update the state function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';;
import * as algoliasearch from "algoliasearch";
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: { hits: [] }
    }
    // set data to string instead of an array  
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    var client = algoliasearch('api-id', 'apikey');
    var index = client.initIndex('');
    //index.search({ query:""}, function(data){  console.log(data) })    
    //index.search({ query:""}, function(data){  console.log("DataRecib=ved. First check this") }) 

    index.search({
      query: "",
      attributesToRetrieve: ['ItemRate', 'Color'],
      hitsPerPage: 50,
    },
    function searchDone(error, data) {
      console.log(data.hits)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="root">
        {
          this.state.data.hits.map(function (data, index) {
            return
            <h1>{this.setState.data.ItemRate}<br />{data.Color}</h1> >            
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
//render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')); 
export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `this.setState` triggers a `render()` call. If you `setState` inside render method, you go into an infinity loop.

You want to update `this.state.data.hits` inside `getData()` function, then you can display the data like so:

```
this.state.data.hits.map(data =>
  <h1>{data.Color}</h1>
)
```

---

For example, if `console.log(data.hits)` logs out the correct data, then you can:

```
this.setState({
  data: {
    hits: data.hits
  }
})
```

---

EDIT:

Using the code you provided, it should be like this:'

```
getData = () => {
  var client = algoliasearch('A5WV4Z1P6I', '9bc843cb2d00100efcf398f4890e1905');
  var index = client.initIndex('dev_twinning');
  //index.search({ query:""}, function(data){ console.log(data) }) 
  // index.search({ query:""}, function(data){ console.log("Data Recib=ved. First check this") }) 
  index.search({
    query: "",
    attributesToRetrieve: ['ItemRate', 'Color'],
    hitsPerPage: 50,
  }, searchDone = (error, data) => {
    this.setState({
      data: {
        hits: data.hits
      }
    })
    console.log(data.hits)
  })
}
```

Comment: at the part where you are able to correctly `console.log` the data, is where you can `setState`. Check updated answer.

Comment: getData(){
   
   
    var client = algoliasearch('A5WV4Z1P6I', '9bc843cb2d00100efcf398f4890e1905');
    var index = client.initIndex('dev_twinning');
    //index.search({ query:""}, function(data){  console.log(data) })
   // index.search({ query:""}, function(data){  console.log("Data Recib=ved. First check this") })
  
  
  
   index.search({ query:"", attributesToRetrieve: ['ItemRate', 'Color'],
   hitsPerPage: 50,}, function searchDone(error, data){ 
    this.setState({
      data: {
        hits: data.hits
      }
    })
 
    console.log(data.hits) }
    )
  }

Comment: thank you for your reply. but i got error like "TypeError: this.setState is not a function"

Comment: I think it's the `cannot read property of setState` error right? Change `getData()` into an arrow function. I will update the answer

Comment: got error like TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: @Lidiyam yea, that's why you need to use arrow function on both `getData` and `searchDone`.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of mistakes -:

- You just need to use `this.state.data.ItemRate` instead of `this.setState.data.ItemRate`.
- You can get state inside .map using arrow functions ( . )=> { . }
- Visit https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/

  ```
  render() {

  return (
    <div id="root" >


    {

     this.state.data.hits.map((data,index) => {

      return<h1>{this.state.data.ItemRate}<br />{data.Color}</h1>
     }
  ```